# Is it okay to make a database query inside a Spark streaming transformation?

Tags: apache-spark, cassandra, spark-streaming

I'd like to process a stream of data coming from RabbitMQ. Specifically, it's a list of changes, and I'd like to filter out changes that have already been made. To do that, I'd need to compare the new data against the existing data in a Cassandra database.

Is it okay to do that within a Spark streaming transformation? Is there some more idiomatic approach I should be considering?

Comment: Well, as long as you can keep up with incoming data, you can do whatever you want inside transformations. But definitely do mapPartitions rather than map, so you only establish a DB-connection per partition and not per row. I would probably also look into any possibility of caching data - perhaps stateful streaming could help you?

Comment: So I have to open a new connection every time I'm called? I presume I can't close over a connection, because my function is serialized and sent to the workers, but is there no way to have a persistent connection? I'll look into caching, but the size of the dataset might make that too expensive. I'd have to cache everything rather than MRU, because I have an API operation that retrieves all the rows for a particular customer.

Comment: And when you say stateful streaming, what do you mean? I'll be using stateful streaming to keep track of various aggregate metrics, but are you suggesting to also keep the actual data as Spark state? Writing it out to C* at some point? I'll read up on this more.

Comment: It all sort of depends on what you are trying to do. I got the impression that you have changes to your Cassandra database coming in through your stream, in which case it might make sense to have a Spark State that you continuously update and then write back every once in a while rather than updating the database continuously. But as I said, I would definitely also look into using a regular cache like say Redis.